# How to increase the UITextView height and X axis value in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitextview

Am working in an iPhone app using UITextView. I am trying to increase the height of UITextView based on it's content length. It is working fine. But, when the height of uitextview increase the UITextView should change the height in up side not increase height in down.

This is the code am trying in my project,

```
    baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 50)];
    baseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:baseView];

    TextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 40)];
    TextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    TextView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    TextView.delegate = self;
    TextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    [baseView addSubview: TextView];

    -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
   {
       CGRect frame = messageTextView.frame;
       frame.size.height = messageTextView.contentSize.height;
       TextView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, frame.size.height);
       baseView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, frame.size.height+20);
   }
```

When the UITextView height is changing the effect textview height will be increase on top side. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method you change the frames, also edit the `frame.origin.y` value of the `textView`

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   CGRect frame = messageTextView.frame;
   frame.size.height = messageTextView.contentSize.height;
   TextView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, frame.size.height); //previous y was 10
   baseView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, frame.size.height+20);
}
```

Nonetheless, I believe you are aware that you have only 10 pixels for the `textView` to go up, as you are adding it to a `BaseView` view.